# Can FaunaDB driver run on Android in some way?

Tags: android, compatibility, faunadb

I need to access FaunaDB from android and there's no REST Api and support is only for java 11, which is not what android uses. The only solution seems to be to use their Scala driver and install Scala to android as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

FaunaDB does not have a native Java driver. However, it does have native GraphQL support. You can use the
[Apollo GraphQL client](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/android/essentials/get-started-java/) to connect to FaunaDB.

To learn more about GraphQL in Fauna follow [this link](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/tutorials/graphql/quick_start).

Comment: There is a java driver (https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/drivers/jvm) but it requires v11 may have some dependencies not compatible with Android.